# Input span not showing as a link

Tags: html, css

The search glass icon in the orange input at the top [of my page here](http://www.inside-guides.co.uk/brentwood/pages/index.html) isn't displaying as a link, so when hovered over the pointer doesn't show.. Any ideas why it might be?

Here's the CSS:

```
.searchGlass {
background-image: url(/images/searchicon.png);
background-position: left 1px;
background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
display: block;
height: 18px;
position: relative;
top: -24px;
width: 15px;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
left: 7px;
}

.hideText {
text-indent: 125%;
white-space: nowrap;
overflow: hidden;
}

.submit {
margin: 1em 0 0 0;
width: 30px;
height: 30px;
text-transform:uppercase;
font-size:15px;
padding: 6px 13px;
cursor:pointer;
border-radius: 20px;
}
```

And html:

```
<div class="left"><input type="submit" class="submit hideText" value=""/><span class="searchGlass hideText">Go</span></div>
```

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try from here:

```
<div class="left">
     <button class="submit"><span class="searchGlass hideText">Go</span></button>
</div>
```

and CSS:

```
.searchGlass {
    background-color: transparent;
    background-image: url("/images/searchicon.png");
    background-position: left 1px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    display: block;
    height: 18px;
    position: relative;
    width: 15px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always submit by javascript:

`<a href="#" onclick="submit();"><span class="searchGlass hideText">Go</span></a>`

Comment: Thanks Sergio, I went with changing it to a button which was the best solution without javascript.

Answer (score -1):

the default display for span is inline, you have to change it to block then float it where you want, then you will be able to but width and height 
try this in CSS

```
.hideText {
  text-indent: 125%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  width:50px; /* 50px is just assumed value, put yours */
  height:50px;
  display:block
  float:left;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It doesn't work with the height/width in and the float removes the image..

Comment: This won't make the icon clickable, also the `.hideText` class is for hiding text, you want to  modify the `.searchGlass`